# Find the mean and variance of a continuous variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance, bounded-variation

Suppose we want to estimate the pH of a mysterious liquid. Let the true
pH be 5. We take t readings and let $X_i$ be the value returned by the $i^{th}$ reading. You should assume that
the readings are independent and that $E(X_i) = 5$ and $var(X_i) = 2$. Let $Y = (X_1 + X_2 + . . . + X_t)/t$ be
the average of these readings.

1) Find the mean and variance of Y

2) How large does t need to be such that P(4.9 < Y < 5.1) ≥ 0.99? Show your work.

Any help with this question would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Expectation is linear. Cheby inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**To get you started**

See that in this case, $Y = \bar{x}$ for $t$ independent events, so we are searching for the sampling distribution of $\bar{x}$.

Assuming the sample size $t$ is sufficiently large, we can say that $Y$ follows a normal distribution with mean $5$ and variance $\frac{2}{t}$

Comment: What I did was add all the expect values of $E(X_i)$. to get the $E(Y)$, and ended up getting $5t$ because there are t readings. Why is the mean of Y just 5 and not 5t?

Comment: That is correct so far, but don't forget that you are also dividing by $t$. Look at the formula for $Y$

Comment: Please tell me if I'm on the right track, gunna edit this in a bit

Comment: So since: the X readings are independent, we get the Y variance from doing
$$Var(Y) = \frac{Var(X_1) + Var(X_2) + Var(X_3)...+ Var(X_t)}{t} = \frac{1}{t} * \sum_{i = 1}^t Var(X)= 2$$

Is my logic right or no?

Comment: I merely stated the variance due to the definition of the sampling distribution. More about deriving the variance can be explained [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

Comment: Particularly the section "Sum of uncorrelated variables
(Bienaymé formula)"

Comment: So from there, I applied the chebyshev equation like so:
$$P(4.9 < Y < 5) \ge 0.99$$
$$\frac{Var(Y)}{t^2} = \frac{2}{t^3}  $$
$$ t^3 = \frac{2}{0.99} $$
$$t = 0.272$$
is this wrong?